# Exclude a header file from the dependencies for a build in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, dependencies, header-files

I have a larger MFC project. Off course the resource.h file is used in a lot of cpp files.

Former VS version tracked the `//{{NO_DEPENDENCIES}}` comment at the start. The result was, that a change to the resource.h didn't cause a full recompile of all files using this header.

How can I achieve this with VS-2017?

I now that I need to manually trigger a recompile or a build all n major changes.

Comment: Hi friend, is there any update? Not sure if my answer helps,and if I misunderstand anything, please feel free to correct me :)

Comment: I have to recheck this. I have projects that share the same RC file. and it seams that the there are some things I don't understand...

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) Any update feel free to contact me.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I achieve this with VS-2017?

You can get details from [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tn035-using-multiple-resource-files-and-header-files-with-visual-cpp?view=vs-2017#_mfcnotes_tn035_including).

The `//{{NO_DEPENDENCIES}}` is still supported in VS2017. If you add a new .rc file in VS2017, it will create a resource.h file, within it the comment will be at the first line.

- From document:

**Visual C++, circumvents the dependency on RESOURCE.H by including the following comment as the first line of the RESOURCE.H file:**

**Also, if you have the need to frequently change symbol values for a certain group of resources, you will probably find it more convenient and safer to break out these symbols into a separate read-only header file, as described in the above section [Including Additional Header Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tn035-using-multiple-resource-files-and-header-files-with-visual-cpp?view=vs-2017#_mfcnotes_tn035_including).**